# Is it possible to create one index for more than one column? hiberanate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, collections, hibernate-mapping

I would like to create only one index or composite index for multiple columns of a collection on xml file. Is there a proper way to do it? I couldnt find anything relevant. I see that it is possible on sql.

Here is my example;

```
<set name="properties" fetch="join" lazy="false" table="PLN_DEMAND_ORDER_ITM_PROPERTY">
    <key>
        <column name="ORDER_ID" index="IDX_PLN_DOIP_ORDER_ID"/> <=
        <column name="LINE_NO" index="IDX_PLN_DOIP_ORDER_ID"/>  <= for both column only one index is needed
    </key>
          .
          .
          .
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Multiple columns can be grouped by simply **specifying the same index name** into the same index as you have clearly done it.
```

This  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182950/how-to-define-index-by-several-columns-in-hibernate-entity) can give you better understanding. hope this helps..