# Hibernate index mapping (double column primary key)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, indexing

Say I have a primary key with two columns (a, b).
Will Hibernate create a singular index on both columns as well?

example output: 
index on a 
index on b 
index on (a,b)

Answer (score 0):

visit : http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/index

[How to define index by several columns in hibernate entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182950/how-to-define-index-by-several-columns-in-hibernate-entity)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I ended up created a multi-column index on a,b alongside individual index's: one on column a, and one on column b.